# Saving a Part into a directory

Tags: java, email, jakarta-mail, attachment

I've googled around enough but I can't find the right solution to my issue.

I'm using javamail to download all the attachments of an email and now I do have the attachments but I would like to store them all in a directory. So my code does create a directory (using file.mkdir()) but I haven't been able to move those attachments into my folder (Attachments). This is what I am using so far:

```
MimeBodyPart part = (MimeBodyPart) multiPart.getBodyPart(i);
    if (Part.ATTACHMENT.equalsIgnoreCase(part.getDisposition())) {
        part.saveFile("/Attachments/" + part.getFileName());
    }
```

Is there a way to save the part into a folder?

Answer (score 0):

Open a FileOutputStream and write the bytes out.

Comment: Actually, FileUtils.moveFileToDirectory from the commons.apache.org did the trick. Thank you though!

Answer (score 0):

You don't say exactly what happens when you try to save the attachment.  Do you get an exception?  Is the attachment stored in the wrong file?  I'm sure you understand that what you wrote tries to save it in the /Attachments directory in the root of your filesystem.

Note also that the filename that comes with a part can be complete garbage.  Consider what should happen if the filename in the part is "../etc/passwd".

Answer (score 0):

I got the absolute path for the file location of where I was trying to save to then use FileUtils from apache to move the file to the directory and then move the directory to another directory.